# Syntax error: "(" unexpected when execute a compiled c program

Tags: linux, shell, c

I try to execute the c binary file **acqv** program in the Shell (this program has been compiled like this on another computer :

```
gcc acqv170104.c -o acqv `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

the command line :

```
$ sudo ./acqv paramA paramB paramC
```

and I got that message

```
acqv: 1: acqv: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've checked the privileges of the script

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1      root      root      20472 Jan 10 14:20 acqv
```

Do I need a to have a special library to execute it?

Comment: side note: you are running this with sudo, and have global write permission. Sort of OK if you are only user, but not a good idea.

Comment: Would have to see the source of the C code. I can not see anything wrong here. Unless you did not post what you did.

Comment: Is `ParamA` etc actually what you typed? It seems contrived.

Comment: *"this program has been compiled like this **on another computer**"* what is the output of `file acqv`?

Comment: the param are the infos to connect to the mysql database

Comment: this program is running in the background (as a service) but don't want to start, this is why I try to run it in the shell.
The program listen another process and retrieve which the process is sending and then write it in the database... I'm not sure exactly what it does because it's a part of another company. The only thing I have to do is to make it running. Also, note that my customer has a similar computer and it runs perfectly, without any issue and the command line is exactly like I gave you...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've provided enough information to determine what the problem is but not how to fix it.

The message ‘Syntax error: "(" unexpected’ evidently comes from a shell. Why is a shell trying to execute your binary? Because the kernel tried and gave up. When this happens, sudo decides that this might be a shell script that lacks a [proper header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and tries to invoke a shell of its choosing (sudo tries to run `sh`).

Why did the kernel fail to run the program? Because the executable is not in a supported format. It isn't even merely due to being compiled for the wrong architecture (e.g. trying to run a 64-bit x86 binary on a 32-bit system or vice versa) or for the wrong operating system (e.g. trying to run a FreeBSD executable on Linux): the kernel does not recognize the file as being in an executable format at all. For example, if you tried to run this on Linux, then it means what you have is not an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary. Among common operating systems, attempting to run a macOS binary on Linux or vice versa would cause this.

Note that the problem is not due to bad permissions or missing libraries. If either of these was the problem, the kernel would report a different error and sudo would not try to run a shell instead.

The solution is to compile the program for the right operating system and the right architecture. If you can't compile on the same machine where you run the program, you may need to set up a [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). If you have no way to recompile the program, there might be a way to run it in an emulator, but this is usually a lot harder and slower than recompiling, so try it only as a last resort.

Comment: thanks for the information. I'm trying to re-intall ubuntu with the same USB key as my customer to have the same version, I'll see if it works... I'll let you know :)

Comment: you're right. When I reinstall the ubuntu with the same USB key, it works! :) Thx a lot!